# PROC SQL subquerying

Tags: sql, sas

I have this table:

| library | table | attribute_exclusion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lib_A | Table A | ('column_A','column_H') |
| lib_A | Table B | ('column_C','column_X') |

And I want to get all columns from `SASHELP.VCOLUMN` in my `HAVE` table except the ones in the column `attribute_exclusion`.

I am trying to do that with the code shown below, but it's returning all columns from both tables, not taking in account my `field_exclusion` values.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
    select upcase(compress(t1.libname)) as libname
        , upcase(compress(t1.memname)) as memname
        , upcase(compress(t1.name)) as name
    from SASHELP.VCOLUMN t1, have t2
    where upcase(compress(t2.library) = upcase(compress(t1.libname))
    and upcase(compress(t2.table)) = upcase(compress(t1.memname))
    and upcase(compress(t1.name)) not in 
        (SELECT t3.attribute_exclusion
        from have t3
        where upcase(compress(t3.library)) = upcase(compress(t1.libname))
        and upcase(compress(t3.table)) = upcase(compress(t1.memname))
        )
    ;
quit;
```

If I just test the code with a implicit value in `attribute_exclusion`, it works, so not sure what I missing here :/

```
proc sql;
create table want as
    select upcase(compress(t1.libname)) as libname
        , upcase(compress(t1.memname)) as memname
        , upcase(compress(t1.name)) as name
    from SASHELP.VCOLUMN t1, have t2
    where upcase(compress(t2.library) = upcase(compress(t1.libname))
    and upcase(compress(t2.table)) = upcase(compress(t1.memname))
    and upcase(compress(t1.name)) not in ('column_C',column_X')
    ;
quit;
```

Thanks in advance for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform a subquery using `not in`, you are using `in` in the sense of the results of the query.

```
SELECT t3.attribute_exclusion
from have t3
where upcase(compress(t3.library)) = upcase(compress(t1.libname))
and upcase(compress(t3.table)) = upcase(compress(t1.memname))
```

Returns (for `tableA`):

```
in ("('column_A','column_H')")
```

For this to match a row in `sashelp.vcolumn`, the column name in vcolumn would need to be exactly `"('column_A','column_H')"` - you cannot get this to match (and exclude) more than one column in `sashelp.vcolumn` by using a single row containing more than one value without some extra coding.

I can't remember how this could be achieved using a single row (if it's possible), so I'll propose a new table structure for `HAVE` which should work:

| library | table | attribute_exclusion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lib_A | Table A | column_A |
| lib_A | Table A | column_H |
| lib_A | Table B | column_C |
| lib_A | Table B | column_X |

Here the subquery returns:

```
column_A
column_H
```

Which is translated by the in to:

```
in ('column_A','column_H')
```

Whereas in the previous version:

```
in ("('column_A','column_H')")
```

Subtle, but different.

Answer (score 1):

Your criteria data is a *first-order* source code snippet that could be used within generated source code that utilizes an `IN` operator.

However, if you presume the exclusion criteria is properly formed, you can leverage `FINDW` to see if a column name of a table is found in the exclusion list.

```
data have;
  length library $8 table $32 name_excludelist $1000;
  input library table name_excludelist;
  datalines;
work a ('P','Q')
work b ('X','Y')
;

data a b c;
  retain P Q R X Y Z;
  call missing (of _all_);
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select libname, memname, name
  from dictionary.columns
  join have
    on libname = upcase(library)
     & memname = upcase(table)
     & not findw(name_excludelist,quote(trim(name),"'"),'(),','tqi')  <----------
  ;
```

You can also unpivot the exclusion criteria list into columnar form for direct metadata comparison.

Example using `EXCEPT` operator.  Other uses of columnar data could be `NOT IN` correlated subqueries.

```
data have_tall;
  set have;
  do index = 1 to countw(name_excludelist, "(),",'tqi');
    length xname $32;
    xname = upcase(dequote(scan(name_excludelist,index,"(),",'tqi')));
    output;
  end;
  keep library table xname;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select libname, memname, upcase(columns.name)
  from dictionary.columns
  join have_tall
    on libname = upcase(library)
     & memname = upcase(table)
  except
  select upcase(library), upcase(table), xname from have_tall
  ;
```